# investigating ip traffic, using tcpdump or any other method to automate the process

Tags: linux, networking, routes, ip

I am trying to verify a new functionality added to the router kernel. So lets assume I added a filter,iptable and such. I have live traffic. I tried to use tcp dump and look into the packet header and see if the new values in the header are there but I am getting random traffic passing through.

I wonder if it is possible to have tcpdump send traffic and dump it so I have specific packets I sent ? or any other linux commands I can use to do the process. I have a destination port that has no traffic but I don't know how I can send to it and capture those packets. I did some reading on sendip and tcpdump and couldnt help myself.

Send packets, tcpdump it or something like that, verify the packet header has what I want and move on with my life.

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Have you tried [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)? There you can define filters and nicely explore the tcp/udp/ip/etc. data.

Comment: That would be manually, I want to automate the test process for future executions as well :(

Comment: If you have a specific host+port you are sending the data, you could tcpdump the traffic to a file with the -w option and using a parsing script to validate the results, is this the approach you are looking for?

Comment: Yes Tcp dump eventually was one way to do it too, but then ended up using netcat manually :)